# How can I find the number of unique undirected edges of a graph using networkx?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a directed bigraph that contains directed and undirected edges.

`networkx_Graph = nx.read_adjlist('graph.txt', create_using=nx.DiGraph())`
I was able to find the number of directed edges using: `len(list(networkx_Graph.in_edges(data=False)))`

But I am trying to find the number of undirected edges.

This is quite easy using the python package `snap`, but I am not finding anything like this in networkx's documentation?

## What is the networkx equivalent of `snap.CntUniqDirEdges()`?

Comment: Can you give a simple example graph?  It's not clear to me how you are creating a graph with directed and undirected edges.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the graph to an undirected graph the calculate the size. NetworkX does not have a function that does this in one shot like `snap` does.

> networkx_Graph.to_undirected().size()

Comment: This is inconsistent with your question - this will convert all directed edges into undirected edges.  This will not tell you how many undirected edges existed originally (though, it's not even clear to me what you would mean by an undirected edge in the original graph).